# id="toptips" and id="topTips" are both valid in same page?

Tags: html, css, case-sensitive, w3c-validation

I'm using two css id with same name in same page but with a difference in capitalization of one letter.

```
<div id="toptips"> </div>
```

and

```
<div id="topTips"> </div>
```

I'm using a firefox plugin to check validation called "HTML VALIDATOR"

http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/

And it's giving error for duplicate id. but when I checked in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options it doesn't showing any error.

Is the Firefox plugin wrong in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, [an id is case sensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), so the plugin is wrong.

However, I wouldn't trust browsers to honor the case sensitivity.

Note that last time I looked at that plugin, it defaulted to using HTML Tidy (which is not a validator) and not OpenSP (which is).

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is [case-sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Case_Sensitivity_in_class_and_id_Names), so it is legal to have both.